# Can't update Shopify Product 'created_at' attribute

Tags: shopify

I can't seem to update the 'created_at' attribute of shopify products through the python api:

```
In[38]: datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
Out[38]: '2015-09-28T16:00:38.843504'
In[39]: n = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
In[40]: p.created_at = n
In[41]: p.save()
Out[41]: True
In[42]: p.created_at
Out[42]: u'2015-09-26T10:21:33-04:00'
```

I can update 'published_at' but this doesn't seem to affect the ordering in the admin, e.g. when viewing the products of a collection by date.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot alter the created_at timestamp. That is why it is called created_at. If you could change it willy nilly, there would be no use in calling it created_at, instead you would call it updated_at or changed_at.

You are surprised you cannot alter the order of products based on their creation date? Welcome to Shopify. If I were you, I would create a grid of your own in an App view, and present the products there, sorted by creation date. I do that, and it works perfect for my App needs. My clients can search, sort and view products in any order they wish, saving them from the lockdown Shopify presentation.

I see in 2024 here that Shopify does offer sorting by creation date. Progress bonanza!